# AWS dynamic inventory python error, how do I fix it?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dynamic, ansible

I am running ansible playbook with AWS dynamic inventory and I just can't make any sense from this error (ec2.py problems):

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /var/opt/git/ansible/project-x/inventory/ec2.py with script plugin: Inventory script (/var/opt/git/ansible/project-x/inventory/ec2.py) had an execution error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/var/opt/git/ansible/project-x/inventory/ec2.py", line 1701, in <module>     Ec2Inventory()   File "/var/opt/git/ansible/project-x/inventory/ec2.py", line 272, in __init__     self.do_api_calls_update_cache()   File
"/var/opt/git/ansible/project-x/inventory/ec2.py", line 538, in do_api_calls_update_cache     self.get_instances_by_region(region)   File "/var/opt/git/ansible/project-x/inventory/ec2.py", line 592, in get_instances_by_region
conn = self.connect(region)   File "/var/opt/git/ansible/project-x/inventory/ec2.py", line 556, in connect     conn = self.connect_to_aws(ec2, region)   File "/var/opt/git/ansible/project-x/inventory/ec2.py", line 581, in
connect_to_aws     conn = module.connect_to_region(region, **connect_args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/__init__.py", line 66, in connect_to_region     connection_cls=EC2Connection, **kw_params)   File
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/regioninfo.py", line 220, in connect     return region.connect(**kw_params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/regioninfo.py", line 290, in connect     return
self.connection_cls(region=self, **kw_params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 103, in __init__     profile_name=profile_name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/boto/connection.py", line 1100, in __init__     provider=provider)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 555, in __init__     profile_name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/boto/provider.py", line 201, in __init__     self.get_credentials(access_key, secret_key, security_token, profile_name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/provider.py", line 297, in get_credentials
profile_name) boto.provider.ProfileNotFoundError: Profile "project-x" not found!

[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /var/opt/git/ansible/project-x/inventory/ec2.py with ini plugin: /var/opt/git/ansible/project-x/inventory/ec2.py:3: Error parsing host definition ''''': No closing quotation

[WARNING]: Unable to parse /var/opt/git/ansible/project-x/inventory/ec2.py as an inventory source

[WARNING]: Unable to parse /var/opt/git/ansible/project-x/inventory as an inventory source

[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: tag_Role_leader


PLAY [tag_Role_leader] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: tag_Role_manager


PLAY [tag_Role_manager] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

When my friend runs this, it works for him, playbook executes fine on tag_Role_leader and manager.  And my aws credentials are correct.

Comment: did you export the `AWS ACCESS KEY` and `AWS SECRET KEY` or `AWS PROFILE`? I think, it can't find the credentials

Comment: I did and now I have less errors but the main one is "Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: tag_Role_leader
" but now I can run ec2.py but I can't grep for tag roles, it should find in the output "leader" or "manager" but it doesn't.

Comment: I solved the problem by cp-ing .aws/config and credentials to root. I must of configured awsume as root and then later did something wrong.